# Python - graph a basic function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have graphed many things before, but any particular reason this basic two blocks won't plot my function? I can change the function to say, `"f = t**2"` and it will plot this, but for my specific `function` that I need, it won't work..

I don't know why it is giving me an error.

**Jupyter screenshot:-**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because the function is expecting a single value, and you passed an array. Maybe try a for loop where each iteration you perform the calculation on the next value in t_span and save the results to an array to be returned.

when posting code, just copy and paste the code in your question and format it, that way it's easier for people to see it and help you.